# 奇数番号は記憶型かどうか調べるもので、丸が4つ以上ある人は「ぼんやり」、6つ以上あったら「かなりぼんやり」である

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

The following sentence is taken from Line 11-13 in [this](https://www.docdroid.net/oraqSdS/img-20170830-0001-new.pdf):

> 奇数番号は記憶型かどうか調べるもので、丸が4つ以上ある人は「ぼんやり」、6つ以上あったら「かなりぼんやり」である。

First, I’m a bit puzzled on this もので. Is it particle も + ので, or もの + (の中)で?
Second, I don’t know whatsoever with this まる and the numbers. I’ve no idea what they are talking about.
Third, I can’t integrate 「ぼんやり」 and 「かなりぼんやり」 , which is also because I’m lacking context (See First and Second).

However, here’s my attempt at full translation.

> Concerning a series of odd digits, out of the search results about which type of memory, the people where the circle is 4 and upwards (it is) ‘absentminded’, and when it is 6 ‘fairly absentminded’.

Comment: I suppose someone else wants to know the definition of "記憶型".

Comment: I assume that this is a psychological test and the odd numbers items are prepared for making sure if your way of thinking is "記憶型"(Rote type?) or other. Then, if you circled in more than or equals to 4 items you are an absent-minded type and if you circled in more than or equals to 6 items you are fairly an absent-minded type.

Comment: @kimiTanaka I agree, I also think is something like that. I put an answer also to explain もので　but someone down-voted it (without comments)  although I though my answer was ok. Since I suppose you're a native speaker would you kindly check and let me know what's wrong, if anything, with it? (It seems we have quite a lot in common by the way lol).

Comment: @Tommy Thanks for the comment.  I also think your interpretation and explanation are correct. Probably you were not in luck. Somebody scrolling up and down, then mis-downvoted. Or, the useage of "もので" can be abstract, so it seemed to have been different than what they thought.haha, we may have many things in common!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "もので" is a a construction that indicates a reason/cause. You could roughly translate it as "because of - for that reason".

The construction is Verb (dict) + もので, and you can think of it as a conjunctive particle that indicates a reason or a cause. You can find more explanations and examples [at this link](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7-mono-de/).

This being said, you can translate your sentence as:

> The odd numbers are what determines whether (the person) is a "memory type" or not, and (because of
>   that) people with 4 or more circles are "absent-minded" while people
>   with more than 6 are "quite absent-minded".

Now some things to be noticed:

1. I'm not sure what a good translation of 記憶型 could be here. Looking at your link it seems that it is one between two types of personalities (記憶、注意) described in some research. Here I decided just to leave it as "memory type".
2. Without more context, it is indeed difficult to judge what those 丸 refer to. However, it seems logical that since we are talking of some personality test and "odd numbers", this probably refers to circling or anyway selecting certain answers. How many will determine the type of personality, absent-minded or quite absent-minded. Notice also that 丸 is what Japanese people commonly use to select "correct" answers in test or in general making selections depending on the context (but I suppose you know about the まる/ばつ convention already).
3. The above is not a literal translation of course but I think it's not what you are asking here. It seems to me the main thing was the もので and the general idea of what's going on.

**Personal interpretation**

Since I'm not sure if what follows is actually true, do not consider it as part of the answer but rather as an intellectual speculation. The answer ended two lines above.

Since you try to break down that もので，I wonder if that もの comes simply from 物 and で isn't just です that, since it's connecting two sentences, simply becomes で.
I mean, I wonder if this construction isn't somehow equivalent or anyway related to something like: 何々。。。Vd物であり、何々。。。 which is literally saying that a certain thing is "something that does V", and I guess you would expect the next sentence to explain some consequence of that. Then over time this became the standard construction もので discussed above.

Comment: Interpreting もので as reason or cause is not wrong but it's a little too much specifying the meaning. To me, it just connects two clauses.

Comment: I don't think to down-vote this, but I feel uncomfortable when I see  ✕ is spelled as 罰. I thought it is spelled as バツ, the katakana.

Comment: @Seesawscene well, technically I didn't say "x = 罰 ". I was just refereeing to the concept of 丸 and 罰 as "right/wrong". Anyway you are right, I think since after all I'm talking of "O" and "X" signs, it would be more appropriate to use kana. In my dictionary actually ばつ for the "x" sign is reported in hiragana. I will update just in case.

Comment: @Tommy: Thanks for the reply. I didn't think you meant "✗＝罰."  And I think you're correct that ☓ comes from 罰, originally. However, it is a very funny thing, but 丸 is okay for me and 罰 isn't. Funny, isn't it?

Comment: @Seesawscene yeah indeed I was just thinking about how you'd feel about 丸 lol

Comment: @Tommy: I just remember ☓ comes from ”batten" and it is written as 罰点. So 罰 is not so wrong, technically.

Answer (score 0):

マル (◯）="yes"

バツ（✕）="No"

> The questionnaire is intended to check the two types of "making mistakes": "easy-to-forget and making mistakes type" and "carelessly-making-mistakes type."  The odd number questions are what determines whether you are an "easy-to-forget type" or not. If you mark 4 or more "yes," you are regarded as an "absent-minded" person. If you mark 6 or more "yes," you are a "quite absent-minded" person.
>   The even number questions are for "carelessly-making-mistakes type."

調べる　もの　で＝調べる　質問　で＝調べる 質問　であり、